# Operating speed of BJT and MOSFET

Tags: transistors, mosfet, bjt

Why is the operating speed of a BJT more when compared to MOSFET?

What makes it faster?

Comment: Regardless, this question would be better asked at the EE stackexchange site.

Comment: There are fast BJTs and slow BJTs. There are fast FETs and slow FETs. If you know how they work you can start figuring out all the engineering trade offs. But it mainly is engineering. The fundamental physics is not tough.

Comment: *Why is the operating speed of a BJT more when compared to MOSFET?* Who says that it is? Under what conditions and in which circuit? This is comparing apples to pears.

Answer (score 5):

MOSFETs are slower than BJTs because of enormous capacitances at its junctions, formed by metal, substrate and the oxide layer. Anyway we still use MOSFETs more in digital circuits because of its low power to switch( gate current = 0 almost) , lesser static power dissipation, ease of fabrication, thermal stability and less leakage (only majority careers form the current in MOSFET).

Answer (score 3):

The reason they are not answering your question is likely because I was able to type "why is a bjt faster than a mosfet" into Google and get [this](https://oscarliang.com/bjt-vs-mosfet/) as the very first search result:

> "Therefore BJTs are more suitable than MOSFETs for driving low-power LEDs and similar devices from Micro Controllers Unit (e.g. Arduino). BJT can switch faster than MOSFET due to the less capacitance at the control pin. However MOSFET is more tolerant to heat (stable to thermal changes) and can simulate a good resistor."

So, to answer your question, a "BJT can switch faster than MOSFET due to [there being] less capacitance at the control pin."

Comment: For more amusement, you could always [link the quoted Google search](http://bfy.tw/F99M).  I do love that site.

Comment: @CortAmmon Both link shorteners and LMGTFY are generally frowned on on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Ron Kyle: Why should there be a correlation between what **they** (don't) answer and what **you** get as first result from a Google search?

Comment: @Curd Lol- I did word that a bit funny. Of course I didn't mean to try to establish a direct cause/effect correlation between their action of not answering and what my first google search return was... I meant to establish a positive correlation between the ease by which the answer was obtained and their unwillingness to answer the question. The easier it was to obtain, the greater their unwillingness. I edited my answer. :)

Comment: @Ron Kyle: ok, but I doubt that this is really the reason. I think they don't answer beause it's simply not true in general. It's like "Why are oranges heavier than apples?"

Comment: @CortAmmon: I was THIS CLOSE to doing the "LMGTFY" thing simply because it was the perfect opportunity and pretty much the exact situation that "LMGTFY" was created for... but I know you're never supposed to give just a link as an answer as it is considered being lazy. Though I did see the irony there, I refrained from doing the "LMGTFY" thing mainly because while I just think it's funny and clever, I know many people who think it is rude and I'm only trying to be nice and helpful. :)

Comment: @Curd - what do you mean they don't answer because it's not true in general? BJTs ARE faster than MOSFETS... and yeah, I'm pretty sure they were refusing to answer because it's HIGHLY frowned upon to be asking questions whose answers can easily be found by typing said question into google instead of here.

Comment: @Rony Kyle: just compare two extremes: a 2N3055 (BJT) is definitely not faster than a BF961 (MOSFET). ... and MOSFETS are used in microprocessores for switching at speeds of several GHz. Obviously not all MOSFETs are that slow.

Comment: @Ron Kyle: also see comments of Jon Custer  and Bimpelrekkie to OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

There is another reason why   MOSFET is slower than bjt  ,in case of MOSFET the conduction of charge carriers takes place laterally where the length is more whereas in case of bjt the charge carriers move vertically from emitter to collector which is less distance so as emitter collector and base are in proximity with each other in bjt the charge moves faster than MOSFET although the capacitance in MOSFET being high is also another significant reason ...

Comment: It's very rare to see lateral MOSFETs these days... Most of the time, you get VDMOS structures.